# Rectangle.FromLTRB return unexpected width / height

Tags: .net, vb.net, rectangles

I'm defining a rectangle like this:

```
Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, 4, 4)
```

To my surprise, r.Width and r.Height are 4:

[image]

I think, the width and height should be 5, not 4.

To make sure I'm not just tired I drew the following scheme to visualize it:

[image]

According to my scheme, width and height should indeed be 5.

Since I don't think MS introduced a bug in such an important function, I would like to ask where I go wrong.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.drawing.rectangle.fromltrb(v=vs.110).aspx) says (for example about "Bottom"):

```
The y-coordinate of the lower-right corner of this Rectangle structure.
```

Somebody wrote in his comment that the last 2 arguments are the width and height, but according to the MSDN docs, this isn't so.

Comment: It starts at 0 and goes for 4 units, it doesn't go to position 4. Think of (5,5,4,4). It starts at 5 and goes for 4 units, it doesn't go backwards to position 4.

Comment: @ChaseRocker MSDN says: "Bottom: The y-coordinate of the lower-right corner of this Rectangle structure." So I think either the docs are wrong or you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the LTRB...I should read better...I thought you were just defining a Rect

Comment: In your example, it's 4 because it's going to point 4, not point 5 as you have in your image.

Comment: @ChaseRocker In my image it does go to point 4. So width should be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 = 5.

Comment: You are wrong, of course.  The .NET Rectangle type doesn't work any differently from RECT, its Right and Bottom properties are also 4.  Graphics libraries and programmers like it when Bottom - Top == Height and Right - Left == Width.

Comment: Then what is wrong about my drawn image? Where does it NOT comply with the MSDN description? It suits the MSDN description perfectly fine in my opinion. And accordingt to my drawn image, the width should be 5. However, .net tells me r.Width is 4.

Comment: The x,y represent the intersection of points, not the area between points as you've drawn in your image.

Comment: @ChaseRocker Is my answer good?

Answer (score 1):

My failure was that I saw the coordinate as a 2-dimensional element, however it's 1-dimensional.

So if we shift the shown image like this, it becomes clear why width and height are 4:

[image]

Comment: Exactly. You've got it.